# string similarity and pattern matching

Tags: c#, .net, string

Say I have strings like these

```
Sam is Boy
Joseph is Boy
Jasmine is Girl
Annie is Girl
Chris is Boy
```

I have a quick and murky way of preparing a C# Dictionary like this..!

```
input.ForEach(i =>
{
    string[] values = i.Split();
    input_dictionary.Add(values[0], values[2]);
});
```

Do we have any other better/optimised way of achieving this, since the input data follows a fixed format like "Name is Gender"?

Comment: By "optimistic", do you mean optimised?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for correction.

Comment: What do you suspect is wrong with method?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it. I wanted to learn if there is a way of applying regex in cases like these or/and do we have any inbuilt things in framework which I didnt knew.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a regex pattern you could use:

```
(.+) is (Boy|Girl)
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for the answer

Answer (score 0):

The following is probably faster, but you should test it.

```
input_dictionary = (from i in input
                    let n = i.IndexOf(' is ')
                    select new { Name = i.Substring(0, n), Sex = i.Substring(n + 4) }
                   ).ToDictionary(i => i.Name, i => i.Sex);
```

You can also the Regex class, which might be faster or slower than the above. It's difficult to say without testing.

Comment: I would prefer this too, except tht you would need to add the IDictionary on the rhs to input at lhs.

Comment: Why would this probably be faster?
That would be helpful info.